# Why can't I pass a string into the function GetDriveTypesA()?

Tags: c++, string, function

So the aim of the program is to find out what drives are available and what they are. However, I cannot seem to pass a string variable straight into `GetDriveTypesA()`. But, if I just do `GetDriveTypesA("C:\\")` it works successfully.

Please can someone help me find a solution to this problem the program is below. Thank you :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    int driveType;
    std::string path;
    int binary[26] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //To save the binary number of the GetLogicalDrives
    std::string  actualDrives[26];
    std::string letters[26] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}; //letters of the alphabet
    DWORD drives = GetLogicalDrives(); //finds the bit mask of logical drives

    for(i=0; drives>0; i++) { //changes the integer into a binary number
        binary[i]=drives%2;
        drives= drives/2;
    }
    for (i=0; i<26; i++){ //finds out what drive letters are available
        if (binary[i]==1){
            actualDrives[i] = letters[i];
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<26; i++){ \trying to find the drive type
        if (actualDrives[i] != ""){
        cout << "Actual drive:";
        cout<< actualDrives[i] <<endl;
        path = actualDrives[i] + ":\\";
        cout << path <<endl;
        driveType = GetDriveTypeA(path); //the part of the code that does not work but does work if a string is just entered
        cout<< driveType << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your compiler have to say about it?

Comment: Try path.data() instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`GetDriveTypeA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea) takes a [C string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/f8d4fe46-6be8-44c9-8823-615a21d17a61), not a C++ `std::string`.

```
UINT GetDriveTypeA(
  LPCSTR lpRootPathName
);
```

Use the [`std::string.c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method:

```
driveType = GetDriveTypeA(path.c_str());
```